# Angular4: router, children (optional) parameters

Tags: angular, router

So, I am looking to produce paths like these:

> matches/:page/:team/:season

where :team and :season are optional parameters
so I could have an url like

```
matches/results/4/2017 or
matches/results/4 or
matches/results
```

all should be valid and come through in `this.route.snapshot.params`

I tried this:

```
  {path: 'matches', children: [
    {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'fixtures'},
    {path: 'competitions', component: CompetitionsPageComponent},
    {path: ':page', component: PageComponent, children: [
      {path: ':team', children:[
          {path: ':season', children:[]}
      ]}
    ]},
  ]},
```

with no luck, only :page comes through as param

Comment: how many values can :page have? is that really a route parameter or just a subpath in your routes?

Comment: The next question is, do you want to modelate the routes that you mention as nested routes or siblings?

Comment: so, :pager can have two other values (results/fixtures) that point to the PageComponent... competitions (that is on the same level) points to another component..... and page will have 2 params (/:team/:season) later on another one (:competition)... they are all part of the PageComponent ... the paths listed above illustrate the logic of what I'd like to achieve..... if I do matches/results/7/2016 .... I would like to get from snapshot params: {page: 'results', team: 7, season: 2016}... on that route and settings above I get only {page: 'results}

Comment: The explanation will take me a while, but is related to the snapshot that you take from the route parameters

Comment: May I ask in which component are you injecting an instance of ActivatedRoute?

Comment: do it on PageComponent..... ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(() => this.route.snapshot.params)
      .subscribe((params) => {

Comment: @DS_web_developer, I think you should define 3 different routes, no children. Otherwise each parameter belongs to the separate segment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something you want to think about are you really wanting child routes or just the same page or each level?  The other example will end up rendering both components ... which might be what you want, but if not then you might spell out each one.

```
{ path: 'matches/results/', component: ResultsComponent, },
{ path: 'matches/results/:page/', component: PageComponent, },
{ path: 'matches/results/:page/:team/', component: TeamComponent, },
{ path: 'matches/results/:page/:team/:season', component: PageComponent, },
```

also note the name you use in the path is the name you need to use in the param selector:

```
params['page']
params['team']
params['season']
```

example code

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
    this.teamService.getTeam(params['team']).subscribe((team) => {
        this.team = team;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I wanted...  well, sort of... but close enough. thanks

Comment: Hey Tim, how would you pass the params to router.navigate when you are to stay on the same component? (but different url params in regards to :team/:season)

Comment: In this example i think you want it to change because they are different components. but if you are using the same component, i think you might want to use query params instead. You can add query params without reloading the component. (but you will want to make sure you process them on load.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following structure:

```
const paths: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'matches',
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'fixtures' },
      { path: 'fixtures', component: FixturesComponent },
      { path: 'competitions', component: CompetitionsPageComponent },
      {
        path: ':page',
        component: PageComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':team',
            component: TeamComponent
            children: [
              {
                path: ':season',
                component: SeasonComponent,
                children: [

                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Depending on in which component you inject `ActivatedRoute`, you will be able to access different route parameters. For example

If you inject `ActivatedRoute` in `SeasonComponent` and do the following:

```
this._route.params.subscribe(p => console.log(JSON.stringify(p)));
```

You will see an object made of page,team and season properties.

If you do the same for `PageComponent`, you will get an object made of only one property, page. If u get the point, if you inject `ActivatedRoute` in the `TeamComponent`, parameters would have only 2 properties.

The fact that you listen to the Router events and then read the properties in the `ActivatedRoute` instance dont make a difference, because the **injected instance** of the `ActivatedRoute` class contains **only** the parameters that where present in the route at the moment that the component, in which the instance is being injected, was generated.

So basically, at least with this approach, is not possible to access from a component at a certain level in the component hierarchy to route parameters further down in it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

@user2623919 answers close enough...

this is what is working for me... all the routes point to the same PageComponent and in my params I get the ones I set....
this way

```
{path: 'matches', children: [
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'fixtures'},
  {path: 'competitions-table', component: CompetitionsPageComponent},
  {path: ':page', component: PageComponent},
  {path: ':page/:team', component: PageComponent},
  {path: ':page/:team/:competition', component: PageComponent},
  {path: ':page/:team/:competition/:season', component: PageComponent}
]},
```

> /matches/results

gives me params `{page: 'results'}` and

> /matches/results/20

gives me  `params {page: 'results', team: '20'}` and so on

Cheers guys

Comment: yup, thats why I asked if you wanted the components to be on nested paths or just siblings :P