# How to tell Route to ignore the ending part

Tags: angular, routes

Angular 12. Both URLs below should be handled by the same component **DishComponent**. (Preferably one entry to handle both):

1. `/menu/:dishid`
2. `/menu/:dishid/whatever_is_optional_and_tobe_ignore`

The last part `/whatever_is_optional_and_tobe_ignore` is free-text decoration only, chef can change it anytime, insignificant and to be ignored. Based on [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434933/angular4-router-children-optional-parameters) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992212/in-angular-what-is-pathmatch-full-and-what-effect-does-it-have), so this in my routing

```
{path: 'menu',
  children:
  [
    { path: ':id',      pathMatch:'full', component:  DishComponent },
    { path: ':id/**',    pathMatch:'full', component:  DishComponent }
  ]
},
{
  path:'**',
  redirectTo:'404'
}
```

Well, `/menu/12/helloworld` ends into **404**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  {
    path: 'menu/:id',
    children: [{ path: '**', component: DishComponent }],
  },
```

A path is only wildcard when it's **exactly** `'**'`

`path: 'menu/**'` literally matches to `mywebsite.com/menu/**` and nothing else

Also you only have to use `pathMatch: 'full'` when there's a concern  that the default `pathMatch: 'prefix'` will trigger unintentionally, which doesn't seem like the case here.